# finding probability in multivariate normal distribution

Tags: python, data-mining, probability

I am using python. I know that to find probability in multivariate normal distribution I have to use following:

fx(x1,…,xk) = (1/√(2π)^k|Σ|) * exp(−1/2(x−μ)T* Σ^-1 *(x−μ))

where x = [x1, x2]

I have different values of x1 and x2.

but here I have to find probability for:

0.5< x1<1.5 and 4.5< x2<5.5

I know how to use this formula for single value of x1 and x2. But I am confused in this case. Please help.

Comment: You would need to find the area beneath the distribution surface on the square bounded by `0.5 < x1 < 1.5` and `4.5 < x2 < 5.5`. In other words you would need to perform a numerical integration over that region.

Comment: But I can't take integration in Python. If I have single values of x1 and x2, I can substitute x=[x1,x2] in the formula.

Comment: [Numeric integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) involves approximating an integral by sampling function points and approximating the function surface. It looks like [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) has tools for numerical integration. Something simple like the [trapezoid rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) you could also try implementing yourself.

Comment: Can I do this using rectangle approximation?

Comment: You could--that is the simplest numerical integration method. The downside is that it is the also most error-prone method. If your function is changing quickly, rectangle approximation can really under- or over-estimate the value of the integral. You can give it a try and see if it works for this case. If the variances are small, this might not be a bad idea for this specific region.

Comment: ok then what value of x1 and x2 should I substitute?

Comment: You will need to do multiple substitutions, essentially dividing the region into small rectangles. I strongly recommend you spend 30 minutes or so reading a tutorial on numerical integration if you want to know what you are doing. I don't feel there is any other way for you to solve this problem.

Comment: @eigenchris Numerical approximation isn't necessary in this case, as there is an exact solution. Numerical approximation should be avoided if possible; it will probably work OK when the region in question is in the middle of the bump, and not so well otherwise, and it may be difficult to know the difference -- the algorithm might very well terminate successfully with an incorrect result.

Comment: @RobertDodier I didn't realize that was true. What would the exact solution be?

Comment: @eigenchris Hmm, I guess I spoke too soon. I tried to work it out and couldn't. At this point I don't have any exact solution, so an approximation seems to be necessary after all. I stand corrected.

Comment: @RobertDodler It's a good thought to have. :) If a function has a closed-form integral than you should definitely use that rather than numeric integration. But in the case of a 2D gaussian I haven't heard of an alternative to numerical methods.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to so is find the area beneath the function for the rectangle bounded by `0.5 < x1 < 1.5` and `4.5 < x2 < 5.5`.

As a quick and dirty solution, you could use this code to do a two-variable Reimann sum to estimate the integral. A Reimann sum just divides the rectangle into small regions and approximates the area under each region as if the function was flat.

Provided you've defined your distribution as the function `f`.

```
x1Low   = 0.5
x1Hi    = 1.5
x2Low   = 4.5
x2Hi    = 5.5

x1steps = 1000
x2steps = 1000
x1resolution = (x1Hi-x1Low)/x1steps
x2resolution = (x2Hi-x2Low)/x2steps
area = x1resolution*x2resolution

x1vals = [x1Low + i*x1resolution for i in range(x1steps)]
x2vals = [x2Low + i*x2resolution for i in range(x2steps)]

sum = 0;
for i in range(len(x1vals-1)):
    for j in range(len(x2vals-1)):
        sum += area * f(x1vals[i],x2vals[j])

print sum
```

Keep in mind that this sum is only an approximation, and not a great one either. It will seriously over- or under-estimate the integral in regions where the function changes too quickly.

If you need more accuracy, you can try implementing  [triangle rule or simpsons's rule](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/SimpsonsRule2DMod.html), or look into [scipy's numerical integration tools](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html).